# Does varnish expose any API function allowing modules to iterate over all header values?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Is there any way for a varnish module to iterate over all the header values in a request? I know there's the [VRT_GetHdr](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/master/include/vrt.h#L309) function for looking up a single header, but I couldn't find anything for getting all header key-value pairs.